# How would I write this in a MS Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement

Here's how I would write it in C.

```
if(x < 50 && x < 0.125y)
    {
    return 0;
    }
else if(x < 50 && x >= 0.125y)
    {
    if(z >= 2a)
        {
        return 50;
        }
    }
else return b;
```

Here's my attempt, it's just a bunch of nested ifs...

```
IIf(([Est_Order_Qty]<50) And ([Est_Order_Qty]<0.125*[Quantity On Hand]),"0",IIf(([Est_Order_Qty]<50) And ([Est_Order_Qty]>=0.125*[Quantity On Hand]),IIf([Est_Order_Qty]<2*[Qty],"50",[Rounded_To_50])))
```

Comment: Your second if will only be entered if `x = 0.125y` because the other condition is already met in the first if. That is how I interpreted it in my answer.

Comment: Are the `>0.125y` and `>=0.125y` correct?

Comment: Crud. The first one is supposed to be x < 0.125y, and second one is x >= 0.125y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IIF((x < 50) AND (x < 0.125 * y), 0,
    IIF((x < 50) AND (x >= 0.125 * y) AND (z >= 2 * a), 50,
       b)
```

or with your attempt

```
IIf(([Est_Order_Qty] < 50) And 
    ([Est_Order_Qty] < 0.125 * [Quantity On Hand]), "0",
    IIf(([Est_Order_Qty] < 50) And 
        ([Est_Order_Qty] >= 0.125 * [Quantity On Hand]),
        IIf([Est_Order_Qty] < 2 * [Qty], "50", [Rounded_To_50]),
        [Rounded_To_50])
)
```

Comment: Thanks! The top code worked. I think you forgot 1 parenthesis at the very end though :) Thanks for all the wonderful answers everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Switch](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx)

```
SWITCH(
x < 50 AND x < 0.125y, 0,
x < 50 AND x >= 0.125y AND z >= 2a, 50,
TRUE, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your if statement correctly, then my answer came out to:

```
    iif(x < 50 And x > 0.125y, "0", iif(x < 50 And x >= 0.125y, iif(2 >= 2a, 50, ""), b))
```

I believe this is it. Let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the first one is supposed to be x < 0.125y, and second one is x >= 0.125y. Does your solution still apply?

Comment: I do not think so. Let me try it again considering that and I'll update it.

Comment: iif(x < 50 And x < 0.125y, "0", iif(x < 50 And x >= 0.125y, iif(2 >= 2a, 50, ""), b)) Is what I got when I tried it again. Let me know what you get. And not that I put "" because I wanted it to return nothing.