# How do I write this if-statement in a MS-Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement

This is how I would write it in C.

```
if (x > 50)
    {
    //Already wrote this
    }

else if((x < 50) && (x > 0))
    {
    if (a < 0.125y)
        {return 0;}
    else if (z >= 50)
        {return 50;}
    else
        {return x;}
    }

else
    { 
    return 0;
    }
```

I tried nesting a ton of iif statements but it got so messy it was unreadable. Is there any more efficient way?

Any help would be wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: In pure Access SQL syntax there is no better way than nest a lot of IIfs

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I write this in a MS Access query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000194/how-would-i-write-this-in-a-ms-access-query)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. And I intended for it to return 0 if x was negative.

Comment: This was the best part @aprough {{For starters}}
*One trick I have done for complex issues is create subqueries that do some of the calculation for the main query.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
iif(x>50,[your code],iif(x > 0, iif(a < .125y,0,iif(z >= 50,50,x)),0)
```

Future note:  this does not seem like a huge nested problem.  I've seen some with 10 or more levels, even hitting the limit (Somewhere @ 10?).  One trick I have done for complex issues is create subqueries that do some of the calculation for the main query.

Your easiest bet for something too complex though, is to just create a public function in a module.  You can then use that just as you normally would any other evaluation in a query.  So...

```
Public Function ReturnMyValue(x as Integer, a as integer, y as integer) as Integer 
'your code here
End Function
```

Then in your query...

```
=ReturnMyValue(x,a,y)
```